# Возврат результата запроса к MySQL на Node.js

Tags: node.js, javascript

Возникла проблема с возвратом результата выборки из базы данных MySQL. Суть проблемы заключается в следующем - как видно из кода ниже имеется некая функция `func()` в которой выполняется запрос к базе данных. Результат запроса нужно записать в переменную `res`, но после выполнения функции переменная остается пустой. Причем если попытаться вывести в консоль переменную `rows` или `res` непосредственно в теле переданной в `connection.query` анонимной функции,то выборка отображается. Подскажите как правильно записать результат во внешнюю переменную и возможно ли это вообще.

В JavaScript и Node.js новичок

```
function func(){
    var res;
    connection.query(query,function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err)
            throw err
        res = rows;
    });
    //сделать что-нибудь с res
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы попались в типичную ловушку новичков: JavaScript код имеет *асинхронную природу*.

В вашем коде вы передаете методу `connection.query` вторым аргументом функцию обратного вызова, которая будет вызвана **только тогда** когда будут получены данные от базы данных. Поток выполнения при этом сразу же переходит к инструкциям, расположенным после вызова `connection.query`. В этом участке кода, данные от БД **еще** не получены, поэтому вы не можете с ними работать. Совсем.

Самым простым решением вашей проблемы является обработка данных БД в функции обратного вызова, переданной в `connection.query`.

Answer (score 0):

node.is асинхронен по сути своей. Данные есть только в каллбеке

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function func(){
  var res;
  connection.query(query,function(err,rows,fields){
    if (err) throw err;
    else res = rows;
  });
  console.log(res)
}
```

Comment: чтобы вывести результат в консоль нужно чтобы res заполнился данными,но этого не происходит